# difr: how-to sbt build of difr

Tags: java, scala, sbt, git-diff

I would like to test and run the "difr" utility as described here : https://github.com/wspringer/difr

But, I am getting the error below.
Could you please advise on how to overcome this issue ?

```
[info] Done updating.
/home/nskalis/app/difr-master/build.sbt:14: error: not found: value defaultExcludes
defaultExcludes in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.scaml"
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: build
[error] build.sbt
[error]      ^
[nskalis@app difr-master]$ sbt build.sbt 
[info] Loading project definition from /home/nskalis/app/difr-master/project
/home/nskalis/app/difr-master/build.sbt:14: error: not found: value defaultExcludes
defaultExcludes in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.scaml"
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r
[info] Loading project definition from /home/nskalis/app/difr-master/project
/home/nskalis/app/difr-master/build.sbt:14: error: not found: value defaultExcludes
defaultExcludes in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.scaml"
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? l
[info] Loading project definition from /home/nskalis/app/difr-master/project
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
[debug] [Loading] Scanning directory /home/nskalis/app/difr-master
[error] Type error in expression
[debug] > load-failed
[debug] > last
```

Comment: The command ran before the first error is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not running difr, but *building* difr. I'm not sure whether that's what you want or not -- if not, follow the instructions there, which have absolutely nothing to do with cloning the repo and building.

Now, the problem you are having building is that the project is somewhat old, in the sense that it hasn't been updated in a while. If you are using a recent SBT version, it won't work. The project *should* have used properties to indicate what SBT version works with it, but it doesn't.

Fortunately, it is easy to do that yourself. Just do this:

```
echo 'sbt.version=0.12.4' >project/build.properties
```

As long as you are using an SBT version newer than that, it will download the older SBT and run that accordingly.

Oh, be sure to use Java 1.7 -- Java 1.8 won't work with it.

Once you have all that in place -- the `build.properties` file and Java 1.7 -- and have performed the changes you want, run this command:

```
sbt assembly
```

That will generate a file called `target/scala-2.9.2/difr.jar`, including your changes, which you can then use as described in the github page of difr.

Comment: thanks Daniel. that took us a step further. now it complains about

Comment: [info] Set current project to difr (in build file:/home/nskalis/app/difr-master/)
[error] Not a valid key: build (similar: loaded-build)
[error] build.sbt
[error]      ^

Comment: @NikosSkalis In the middle of that paste in your question, you do `sbt build.sbt`. You dont' pass the configuration file to sbt, you just run `sbt`, and go on from there -- there's a `help` command on sbt console if you need.

Comment: in other words ./src/main/resources/diff.scaml should be passed to sbt. using the -h for sbt does not provide any option to specify the configuration .scaml file. so i guess this should be somewhere referenced (?) please advise.

Comment: @NikosSkalis Again, if you want to run difr, follow the instructions on its github page.

Comment: i would like to customize the .html produced. with a .jar file this is not possible.

Comment: sbt community says that this tag would help getting answers, as this is their official way of getting support.

Comment: @NikosSkalis Didn't you change `./src/main/resources/diff.scaml`?

Comment: no. not any changes have been applied to the original source code.

Comment: @NikosSkalis Then how do you expect to customize the html produced? And why wouldn't a jar file be enough?